Migrating SGE profile to snakemake >= 8
In snakemake 7 I was able to run a SGE profile with:
cluster-config: cluster.yaml
cluster: qsub -V -cwd -l highp,h_data={cluster.mem},h_rt={cluster.time},nodes={cluster.nodes} -pe shared {cluster.cpus} -o {cluster.output} -e {cluster.error}

cluster.yaml:
__default__:
    time: "05:00:00"
    mem: 20g
    cpus: 1
    nodes: 1
    output: "{out_dir}logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards.sample}.out"
    error: "{out_dir}logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards.sample}.err"

In snakemake 8 I installed snakemake-executor-plugin-cluster-generic and changed the profile to:
executor: cluster-generic
cluster-generic-submit-cmd: qsub -V -cwd -l highp,h_data={resources.mem},h_rt={resources.time},nodes={resources.nodes} -pe shared {resources.cpus} -o {resources.output} -e {resources.error}

default-resources:
    mem: 20g
    time: "'05:00:00'"
    cpus: 1
    nodes: 1
    output: "'{out_dir}logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards.sample}.out'"
    error: "'{out_dir}logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards.sample}.err'"

It runs, but the output and error log names are used literally instead of the variables being interpreted. How can I specify rule specific wildcards, the rule name and a custom variable out_dir so the the submit cmd uses it like it used to in version 7?
Output: {out_dir}logs/cluster/{rule}.{wildcards.sample}.err
Expected output: my_dir/logs/cluster/align_rule.my_sample.err
